# onmouseover not working in browsers

Tags: html, css

I am making a simple gallery page using html and css. I coded this onto a html viewer and it was working fine however when I opened it up in google chrome and IE the onmouseover is not working. When you go over a selected thumbnail, it is supposed to be display a larger image in the bottom box however it does not work. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong. Help would be much appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title>Gallery</title>

<style type="text/css">
body {
background: #222;
margin-top: 100px;
}

h3 {
color: #eee;
font-family: Verdana;
}

.thumbnails img {
height: 100px;
border: 4px solid #555;
padding: 1px;
margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.thumbnails img:hover {
border: 4px solid #00ccff;
cursor:pointer;
}

.preview img {
border: 4px solid #444;
padding: 1px;
width: 800px;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>


<div class="gallery" align="center">


<div class="thumbnails">
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=img1.src" id="img1" src="http://i60.tinypic.com/2qjj62b.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=img2.src" id="img2" src="http://i60.tinypic.com/mb4c21.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=img3.src" id="img3" src="http://i61.tinypic.com/35avvpw.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=img4.src" id="img4" src="http://i60.tinypic.com/29qnjme.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=img5.src" id="img5" src="http://i62.tinypic.com/zkmvd2.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=img6.src" id="img6" src="http://i61.tinypic.com/oqezus.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=img7.src" id="img7" src="http://i57.tinypic.com/1tx6oj.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>  
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=img8.src" id="img8" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/143onsj.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=img9.src" id="img9" src="http://i61.tinypic.com/2l16qf.jpg"  alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=img0.src" id="img0" src="http://i61.tinypic.com/21l0own.jpg"  alt="Image Not Loaded"/>

</div></br>

<div class="preview" align="center">
    <img id="preview" src="http://i60.tinypic.com/2qjj62b.jpg" alt="No Image Loaded"/>
</div>

</br>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm sure you will have to use Javascript for this. If you can't or don't want to, check out [compass](http://compass-style.org/) or [sass](http://sass-lang.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still stand by my comment but if you are able to use Javascript and JQuery, the following code works:

```
$(function(){
    $('.thumbnails img').hover(function(){
        $('#preview').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
    },null);
});
```

What this does is change the src of the image in the preview div with what ever image is moused over.

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2A4Z/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way -

```
var thumbs = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbnails img');
for(var i = 0; i < thumbs.length; i++) {
    thumbs[i].addEventListener('mouseover',
    function(e) {
        console.log(e.target.src);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try making changes

```
<img onmouseover="preview.src=img1.src" id="img1" src="http://i60.tinypic.com/2qjj62b.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
```

to

```
<img onmouseover=bigImg(this) id="img1" src="http://i60.tinypic.com/2qjj62b.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Better add a data attribute to the images with the source image and then use javascript/jQuery to get it with for example in jQuery

```
$(".thumbnail img").on("mouseover", function (){
     $(this).attr("src") = $(this).attr("data-previewsrc");
});
```

Or something of that nature (typing code on a phone is not ideal)

Answer (score 0):

Onmouseover attribute is for javascript use not for what you are doing.You add javascript in this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the elements and then operate on them:

Add this code to your JavaScript file:

```
window.onload = addSrcs; // make sure images and other content has loaded, and fire addSrcs

function addSrcs() {
    var thumbs = document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnails img"), // the thumbnails
        bigBox = document.querySelectorAll(".preview")[0]; // the big box

    for (var i = 0; i < thumbs.length; i++) { // iterate over thumbs
        // on mouseover
        thumbs[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function (e) { 
            var src = e.target.src; // get the image's src
            bigBox.src = src; // set it to bigBox's src
        });
    }
}
```